# Huawei phone "immortal" icon on xfce Desktop

Tags: xfce

I plugged in my Huawei usb phone on linux (Slackware 14.2) 
I take some photos from it..ok.
I disconnect it correctly,using first umount on desktop icon,then unplug usb cable,but another icon still alive with the device unplugged.
Why?How to remove it?

[image: The device unplugged is still here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably is a bug of Slackware, or of Xfce version of Slackware 14.2
With newest distro like Fedora 30 or Slackware current all is working fine.